# How to efficiently iterate list of data.frame as an input for custom function?

Tags: r, loops, functional-programming

I have list of data.frame as an input for my custom function, I expect custom function return multiple list of data.frame. I did some code changes on my function, but it return unexpected output. Can anyone suggest me how to improve the code in custom function ? Where I went wrong on my code? Any hint?

data

```
myList <- list(
  foo = data.frame( start=seq(1, by=4, len=6), stop=seq(3, by=4, len=6)),
  bar = data.frame(start=seq(5, by=2, len=7), stop=seq(7, by=2, len=7)),
  bleh = data.frame(start=seq(1, by=5, len=5), stop=seq(3, by=5, len=5))
)
```

custom function need to optimized:

```
func <- function(set) {
  # check input param
  stopifnot(is.list(set))
  output <- list()
  require(dplyr)
  for(id in 1: seq_along(set)) {
    entry <- set[[id]]
    self_ <- setdiff(entry, entry)
    res <- lapply(set[-id], function(ele_) {
      joined_ <- setdiff(entry, ele_)
    })
    ans <- c(list(self_), res)
    names(ans) <- c(names(set[id]),names(set[-id]))
    output[id] <- ans
  }
  return(output)
}
```

desired output

I expect my custom function will return multiple list of data.frame object.Can anyone give me some idea? Thanks

Comment: What exactly is `func` supposed  to do? Never mind its output format for now; what calculation are you trying to perform on the input?

Comment: *"always using list is boring"*??? What do you mean by this? Lists are effective and flexible. You can give them interesting names if that will make you happier. *"Which data.structure in R is more suitable for storing very big multiple list of data.frame"* in base R, there are two structures that could have lists of data frames in them: lists and environments. Other than *boredom*, what are your issues with using lists?

Comment: Your example is not reproducible. The "improved" function does not seem to do anything. My answer addresses the intent of your original example. I can't give you an answer more specific than that because your example is insufficient. We can't read your mind.

Comment: I was wrong about implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still having a little trouble understanding your intent, but here's a suggestion for a cleaner solution.

First, it's often much easier to store data as a flat dataframe:

```
library(plyr)
df <- ldply(df.list, rbind, .id = 'group1')

   group1 V1 V2
1       a  1  1
2       a  1  0
3       a  1  4
4       a  2  5
...   
18      c  4  3
```

Then we can use plyr to loop through the combinations of the two groups and compute their set differences:

```
df.setdiff <- ddply(df, .(group1), function(x) {
    comparisons <- subset(df, group1 != x$group1[1])
    colnames(comparisons) <- c('group2', 'V1', 'V2')
    res <- ddply(comparisons, .(group2), function(y) {
        return(setdiff(x[c('V1', 'V2')], y[c('V1', 'V2')]))
    })
})
```

This produces a single data frame:

```
   group1 group2 V1 V2
1       a      b  1  1
2       a      b  1  0
3       a      b  1  4
4       a      b  2  5
5       a      b  3  0
6       a      b  0  2
7       a      c  1  4
8       a      c  2  5
9       a      c  3  0
10      a      c  0  2
...
24      c      b  0  3
```

Some comparisons appear twice, since each group can appear in the "group1" or "group2" column, and my code does not skip those duplications, but this should get you started.

Comment: you are right. I indeed wrong on implementation. Thank you.